# INNER JOIN com 3 tabelas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho 3 tabelas

**TB_ContratoCotista:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]


**TB_Contrato:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**TB_Cotista:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de relacionar os valores da tabela **TB_Contrato** com **TB_Cotista**,
porem do jeito que consegui só retorna o resultado da **TB_Contrato**.
O que estou errando ?

```
SELECT * FROM TB_Contrato
INNER JOIN (SELECT id_contrato FROM TB_Cotista
            INNER JOIN TB_ContratoCotista
            ON TB_Cotista.id_cotista = TB_ContratoCotista.id_cotista) AS VAI
ON TB_Contrato.id_contrato= VAI.id_contrato
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Basta fazer 2 INNER JOIN relacionando as chaves das tabelas.

```
SELECT * FROM TB_ContratoCotista
INNER JOIN TB_Contrato ON TB_Contrato.id_contrato = TB_ContratoCotista.id_contrato
INNER JOIN TB_Cotista ON TB_Cotista = TB_ContratoCotista.id_cotista
```

Você pode definir quais campos aparecem no select:

**Retornando as colunas de todas as tabelas**

```
select * from...
```

**Retornando as colunas apenas da tabela TB_Contrato**

```
select TB_Contrato.* from...
```

Comment: Perfeito, estava tentando fazer de outra forma erá mais fácil que imaginei.