# Buscar colunas de duas tabelas que não estão relacionados diretamente

Tags: sql, query

Tenho 5 tabelas: `cliente`, `produto`, `compra`, `compra_produto` e `fornecedor`.

E os seguintes relacionamentos:

> ```
> compra (fk_cliente)
> compra_produto (fk_compra)
> compra_produto (fk_produto)
> produto (fk_fornecedor)
> ```

Quero mostrar os clientes e fornecedores de seus produtos (comprados). Mas não consigo montar a *query*.

Comment: Qual o problema ?

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72710/inner-join-com-3-tabelas

Comment: Obrigado VME, resolveu.