# Filtrar dados com INNER JOIN - MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, algoritmo-de-busca, filtro

Boa tarde, sou novo no grupo queria saber onde estou errando...

Tenho uma busca no banco de dados assim

**

```
SELECT * FROM Users INNER JOIN naturezanegocio ON Users.emaillogin = naturezanegocio.emaillogin
AND Users.paisorigem = '1'
AND Users.cidade = 'são paulo'
AND Users.estado = 'SP'
AND Users.numfuncionario > '0' < '10'
AND Users.registro = 'sim'
AND Users.investimento = 'sim'
AND Users.interesseparceria = 'sim'
AND Users.niveis_acesso_id = '0'
AND naturezanegocio.natureza IN ('2', '0', '0')
INNER JOIN tecnologia ON tecnologia.tecnologia IN ('5', '0', '0')
```

**

e preciso que retorne apenas o usuario que tenha todas essas requisições, mas ele não filtra tudo de uma vez e sim tabela por tabela que acaba me retornando usuarios invalidos por nao atender todos requisitos...

onde errei?

Comment: Esse JOIN com TECNOLOGIA, você não está associando a nada da consulta de Users e NATUREZANEGOCIO. Uma das falhas está aí.

Comment: imaginei isso, mas não consegui pensar em uma solução para resolver isso, saberia como ?

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente é um erro de sintaxe

> Sintaxe correta:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

FONTE: [www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Comment: no caso eu uso 3 tabelas

Comment: Só usar 2 INNER JOIN; ex: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72710/inner-join-com-3-tabelas

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim, creio que lhe auxiliará

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    Users
        INNER JOIN
    naturezanegocio ON Users.emaillogin = naturezanegocio.emaillogin
        INNER JOIN
    tecnologia ON tecnologia.tecnologia = (Algum Identificador que Possua na tabela Users para fazer referencia)
WHERE
            Users.paisorigem = '1'
        AND Users.cidade = 'são paulo'
        AND Users.estado = 'SP'
        AND Users.numfuncionario > '0' < '10'
        AND Users.registro = 'sim'
        AND Users.investimento = 'sim'
        AND Users.interesseparceria = 'sim'
        AND Users.niveis_acesso_id = '0'
        AND naturezanegocio.natureza IN ('2' , '0', '0')
        and tecnologia.tecnologia IN ('5', '0', '0')
```

Comment: (Algum Identificador que Possua na tabela Users para fazer referencia)

Todas as tabelas tem como referencia emaillogin, testei Users.emaillogin e não voltou nenhum resultado

Comment: consegui fazer funcionar com o exemplo que me deu acima irei postar a solução,
o segundo INNER JOIN ficou assim
"INNER JOIN tecnologia ON tecnologia.emaillogin = Users.emaillogin"

Answer (score 0):

Solução

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    Users
        INNER JOIN
    naturezanegocio ON Users.emaillogin = naturezanegocio.emaillogin
        INNER JOIN
    tecnologia ON tecnologia.emaillogin = Users.emaillogin
WHERE
            Users.paisorigem = '1'
        AND Users.cidade = 'são paulo'
        AND Users.estado = 'SP'
        AND Users.numfuncionario > '0' < '10'
        AND Users.registro = 'sim'
        AND Users.investimento = 'sim'
        AND Users.interesseparceria = 'sim'
        AND Users.niveis_acesso_id = '0'
        AND naturezanegocio.natureza IN ('2' , '5', '0')
        and tecnologia.tecnologia IN ('5', '6', '0')
        group by Users.emaillogin
```